# $A$ tridiagonal positive definite matrix, $2D-A$ also?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a tridiagonal symmetric positive-definite matrix.

How to show that $2D-A$ is also a symmetric positive-definite matrix and then, the Jacobi method converges ?

The Jacobi method is $Dx^{k+1} = (D-A)x^k +b$.

I write : $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & & & \\ b_1 & a_2 & b_2 & & \\ & b_2 & a_3 &... & \\ & & ... & ... & b_{n-1}\\ & & & b_{n-1} & a_n \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $2D-A$ is necessary symmetric. But I don't know how to prove it's positive defined. If $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $2a_k - \lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $2D-A$. But how to prove it's positive ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: Observe that changing the sign of the $b_i$'s also changes the sign of the corresponding co-factor in the determinant of the principal minors. Therefore the determinants of the principal minors stays the same.

Comment: Thank you ! But do you know why the fact that $2D-A$ is symmetric and positive definite implies that the Jacobi method converges, i.e. $\rho(D^{-1}(D-A)) = \rho(I_n-D^{-1}A) < 1$ ?

Comment: I assume $D$ means the diagonal part of $A$. Then, $D$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix (since $A$ is positive-definite). Hence, $D^{-1}$ is also a symmetric positive-definite matrix, and thus has a well-defined symmetric positive-definite square root $S = \sqrt{D^{-1}} = D^{-1/2}$. Now, $A$ is positive-definite; thus, $SAS^T$ is positive-definite as well. Denote this positive-definite symmetric matrix $SAS^T$ by $B$. Then, $B = SAS^T = SAS$ is conjugate to $SSA = D^{-1}A$, so the eigenvalues of $D^{-1}A$ are the same as those of $B$. Thus, ...

Comment: ... in particular, $\rho\left(I_n - D^{-1}A\right) = \rho\left(B\right)$. It thus remains to show that $\rho\left(B\right) < 1$. In other words, it remains to show that all eigenvalues of the positive-definite symmetric matrix $B$ lie strictly between $0$ and $2$. The fact that they are $> 0$ is clear (since $B$ is positive definite), so it remains to prove that they are $< 2$. But the definition of $S$ yields $S^2 = D^{-1}$, thus, $D = S^{-2}$ and therefore $SDS = SS^{-2}S = 1$. Also, $B = SAS$, so ...

Comment: ... that $2 - B = 2 - SAS = S \left(2D-A\right) S$ (this follows from $SDS = 1$). In view of $S = S^T$, this rewrites as $2 - B = S^T \left(2D-A\right) S$. Hence, the matrix $2 - B$ is symmetric positive-definite (since $2D-A$ is symmetric positive-definite). Therefore, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $< 2$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You really helped me ! :)